# static constexpr member function in templated using expression not found

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr, using-directives

For the following code

```
#include <array>

template<unsigned MaxP, typename type>
struct kernel
{
  static constexpr unsigned max_pole(unsigned P)
  { return P>MaxP? MaxP:P; }

  template<unsigned P>
  using array = std::array<type,max_pole(P)>;          // wrong?

  template<unsigned P>
  static void do_something(array<P> const&, array<P>&);
};
```

gcc 4.7.0 (g++ -c -std=c++11) gives

```
error: ‘max_pole’ was not declared in this scope
```

Is this correct (behaviour of the compiler)? Note that if I resolve `max_pole` by replacing it with `kernel::max_pole` on the line indicated, it compiles fine.

**EDIT** Reported to bugzilla, accepted as bug c++/55992, see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55992. Also occurs with gcc 4.7.x and 4.8.0.

Comment: Just tested: same for `g++ 4.7.2` Someone has a newer version like 4.8? Maybe this is a bug which was fixed...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your template compiles fine with Clang 3.2. I strongly believe it is a GCC bug (which is present in GCC 4.7.2 as well, btw). Change notes for GCC 4.8.0 do not seem to mention any such bugfix.

Also notice, that the compilation error disappears if you remove the declaration of `do_something<>`, which should not make any difference.

One more hint: while this template does **not** compile on GCC 4.7.2:

```
template<unsigned MaxP, typename type>
struct kernel
{
    static constexpr unsigned max_pole(unsigned P)
    { return P>MaxP? MaxP:P; }

     template<typename T>
     using array2 = int[max_pole(3)]; // ERROR!

     static void do_something(array2<int> const&, array2<int>&);
};
```

This template **does** compile:

```
template<unsigned MaxP, typename type>
struct kernel
{
    static constexpr unsigned max_pole(unsigned P)
    { return P>MaxP? MaxP:P; }

     // template<typename T>  <--- removed
     using array2 = int[max_pole(3)]; // OK

     static void do_something(array2 const&, array2&);
};
```

Since `max_pole` is **in both cases** an *unqualified independent name*, the lookup strategy should be the same in both cases, and it is not. To me, this qualifies it as a bug.

Comment: So, according to your research, this situation happens specifically when you mix two new C++11 features (`constexpr` + alias templates) under certain circumstances. The perfect scenario then for a compiler bug.

Comment: @Gorpik: yes, I have the same feeling

Comment: @Walter : Mind posting a link? :-]

Comment: When you make the `constexpr` function a template, it fails even in _clang 3.2_.